# PeeWee model has no 'select' attribute error

Tags: python-3.x, peewee

I'm in the process of creating an application for a personal project I'm working on that involves Python 3, peewee, and (for the moment) Sqlite3. In main, I'm importing a 2 model classes (student and course) which are subclasses of a basemodel class I create.

**The import statements located in main.py:**

```py
from models.course import Course
from models.student import Student
```

**The models/BaseModel.py**

```py
from peewee import *

db = SqliteDatabase('database/attendance.db')


class BaseModel:

    class Meta:
        database = db
```

**The models/course.py**

```py
from peewee import *
from models.basemodel import BaseModel


class Course(BaseModel):
    cid = PrimaryKeyField()
    title = TextField()
    active = BooleanField()

    class Meta:
        table_name = 'courses'
```

When I try to do a simply query to retrieve courses, I receive an error message.

**Example query:**

```py
active_courses = Course.select().where(Course.active == True)
```

The error message I receive is:

*AttributeError: type object 'Course' has no attribute 'select'*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your BaseModel class needs to extend peewee.Model:

```
class BaseModel(peewee.Model):
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks. That's what I get for coding at 3am. I couldn't see the forest for the trees.